# How to get a version of pgAdmin III working correctly with the PostgreSQL 9.4 (Ubuntu 14.10 x64)?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I have installed **postgresql-9.4** and **pgAdmin III** on **Ubuntu 14.10 x64**:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
sudo apt-get pgadmin3
```

However using **pgAdmin** with **PostgreSQL** I faced with the warning

> Warning: The server you are connecting to is not a
>   version that is supported by this release of pgAdmin III.
>
> pgAdmin III may not function as expected.
>
> Supported server versions are 8.4 to 9.3.

1) How to get a version of **pgAdmin III**  do I use?

2) How to uninstall current version of **pgAdmin** and to install the correct version of **pgAdmin**?

Thank you.

Comment: mentioning that it is a **pgAdmin III 1.18.1** documentation. So I tend to think that I really use obsolete **pgAdmin III 1.18.1**. Is there a more correct and reliable way to get the version of **pgAdmin**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a known bug: [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/+bug/1379298)

The bug thread suggests to try and **use pgAdmin 1.20**. You can download it here: [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/pgadmin3)

Answer (score 20):

PostgreSQL maintains a repository of apt packages. You can follow the instructions on their wiki at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Basically, they boil down to:

```sh
# add the repository
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

# install their key
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```sh
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

That worked fine for me on Ubuntu 12.04, and I have now pgadmin3 v. 1.20.